# LWJGL / don't render a wall if the camera looks at the player through it

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I was wondering if there is any standard way of not rendering a wall when the camera has to look at the player through it. In my game the camera is completely free to rotate around the player. When the camera is looking at the player with a high pitch it can see over the wall most of the time at the player, but if the camera's pitch is low, then a lot of the time it ends up just staring at a wall, and you can't really tell what is going on behind it. If anyone knows a way I could go about this that would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have a very valid point here, that walls can easily obstruct the player in a third-person view, but the ideal solution is ***probably not*** going to be to remove the wall that obstructs the player. Depending on how the world is constructed, if you remove the polygon(s) belonging to a wall you may very well create a hole in the world that only exposes the back-sides of polygons (which are usually culled); so an unintentional glimpse into the abyss.

Actually, the way this is often implemented is to use the stencil buffer to draw parts of your character using different shading.

#### Consider the following very crude diagram <sub>(I am too lazy to draw something for real):</sub>

```
  |\
  | \***
  |  \**
  |  x\* 
  |  xx\
  |     \
  -------
```

Imagine the triangle is your wall and the rectagle is your player. Rather than removing the triangle entirely, the parts that are inside (behind in your case) the triangle are rendered differently (filled with `x`). Now, the wall stays in place but you draw the part covered by the wall in a special way to give the player feedback without destroying part of the actual world.

This would be a two-pass operation, first you clear your stencil buffer to **0x00** and draw your character normally with stencil testing enabled. When the depth test fails for your character, flag the stencil buffer at that position by setting bit **1**.

On your second pass, draw the model again, but this time disable depth testing and only draw it where the stencil buffer has bit **1** flagged. Likewise, in this second pass, do something to change the visual appearance of the drawn model (e.g. give it a green glow, only draw a wireframe, use additive blending or whatever - be creative).

---

### Here is a rough outline of what this would look like in terms of code:

#### First Pass <sub>(render as usual):</sub>

```
glClearStencil (0x00);
glClear        (GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable       (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable       (GL_STENCIL_TEST);

glStencilFunc  (GL_ALWAYS, 1,          1      );
glStencilOp    (GL_KEEP,   GL_REPLACE, GL_KEEP);

// Draw your model as usual
```

#### Second Pass <sub>(only draw parts of the model that failed a depth test the first time):</sub>

```
glDisable      (GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glStencilFunc  (GL_EQUAL, 1,       1      );
glStencilOp    (GL_KEEP,  GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);

// Draw your model again, but with some special visual characteristic of your choosing.

glDisable      (GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

---

#### Here is what this actually looks like when implemented in a real game <sub>(Torchlight):</sub>

[image]

Notice the ghostly blue parts where the player's model is behind the railing?

Comment: You do need a pixel format with a stencil buffer for this to work of course. But most OpenGL frameworks default to 24-bit depth already so tacking on an 8-bit stencil buffer is not going to hurt anything. Those 8-bits would still take up memory, but go unused otherwise.

Comment: thanks for the reply, that method is very interesting and I will definitely consider using it for future projects. At the moment the game I am making is a simple 2.5D game, where I am rendering 2D characters in a 3D space, so my actual models are simple flat rectangles with a texture drawn for the front and back face. Would this method work for the texture alone, or is it intended to only be used by rendering the wire-frame of the object on the second pass?

Comment: It does not matter what you draw on the second pass, just as long as it is not exactly the same thing (because if it were, there would be no point in doing this in the first place). So even if all you do on the second pass is tint your object (sprite/texture) red that would be enough to let the player know the object is behind something. This technique is even used in 2D Zelda-like games, where the sprite passes under a platform 1 floor above and the player needs some visual feedback to figure out where the sprite is even though it is partially or completely covered.

Comment: Awesome, you have been a great help, ill see where this takes me :)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this only works if you draw the world before your player/models. Typically that is the order things are rendered in anyway, but this technique absolutely *requires* that order.